# Android studio - register button doesnt work :c (related to my sql database)

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, database

Hey guys so i am creating an application. allows users to register to a database. but apparently the register button doesnt work once all the details have been written. can anyone see what the problem is?

ps - i have added internet permission in the manifest file. also my register.php file is working. i tested it by manually putting information.

my code

```js
package com.example.naveen.driver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);

        final EditText rname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rname);
        final EditText rusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rusername);
        final EditText rpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remail);
        final EditText remail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
        final EditText rcarmodel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rcarmodel);
        final EditText rcaryear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rcaryear);
        final EditText rreg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rreg);
        final Button rbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rbutton);

        rbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                final String name = rname.getText().toString();
                final String username = rusername.getText().toString();
                final String email = remail.getText().toString();
                final String password = rpassword.getText().toString();
                final String caryear = rcarmodel.getText().toString();
                final String carmodel = rcaryear.getText().toString();
                final String carreg = rreg.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if(success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPage.this, LoginPage.class);
                                RegisterPage.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterPage.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, email, carmodel, caryear, carreg, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterPage.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

RegisterRequest.java

```js
package com.example.naveen.driver;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by NAVEEN & CHRISTO on 21-Sep-17.
 */

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://dipteran-thin.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, String email, String carmodel, String caryear, String carreg, Response.Listener<String> listener){
            super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
            params = new HashMap<>();
         params.put("name", name);
         params.put("username", username);
         params.put("password", password);
         params.put("E-mail", email);
         params.put("carmodel", carmodel);
         params.put("caryear", caryear);
         params.put("caryear", carreg);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

activity_register_page.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.naveen.driver.RegisterPage">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rreg"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rreg" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rusername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rname"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rname"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rname" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rreg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/remail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rusername"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rusername"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rusername"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-mail "
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/remail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/remail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/remail"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rcarmodel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Car - Model"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rpassword"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rpassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rpassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rcaryear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rcarmodel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rcarmodel"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Car - Year"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rcarmodel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rreg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Reg No"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rcaryear"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just try adding the logcat inside the register button and see if it is coming inside it or not. Just put logcat inside the rButton.setOnlickListener(). And tell me now.

Comment: sorry i dont get what u mean?

Comment: see my edited answer below and try doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your problem, since you are adding the *params* after making the request to server, you need to add params before making a call to the server. Do like this and get your job done!

```
rbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            final String name = rname.getText().toString();
            final String username = rusername.getText().toString();
            final String email = remail.getText().toString();
            final String password = rpassword.getText().toString();
            final String caryear = rcarmodel.getText().toString();
            final String carmodel = rcaryear.getText().toString();
            final String carreg = rreg.getText().toString();

            //adding your params here will get the data to be passed in your db and make your job done
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, email, carmodel, caryear, carreg, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterPage.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterPage.this, LoginPage.class);
                            RegisterPage.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterPage.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    });
```

**EDITS**

Your problem is in you RegisterRequest Class you have used the wrong way of adding the things in your params.

Use like this to get your result in your **ResgisterRequest Class**

Use  `params.add()`

despite of using this `params.put()`

Hope it'll help you!

Comment: i am getting "cannot resolve symbom response request error"        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, email, carmodel, caryear, carreg, responseListener);

Comment: Alright we are into business then, atleast we know that the button is working. Now look into your code and check your code of sending the details, the problem is there only. Now I've resolved your problem that your button was not working. Now do it by your self

Comment: @user3431791 see my edited answer and try doing like this, register button was done from my side and now make changes in your RegisterRequest class and tell me if it works

Comment: Hi. i replaced the params.put() to params.add() but .add is being highlighted RED.  eg params.add("name", name);

Comment: also i read this "//adding your params here will get the data to be passed in your db and make your job done". i tried doing that but same problem.